# jQuery: How to use setTimeout for temporary change of background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I am trying to temporarily change the background color of a table row, then switch back to its original color and do something else, e.g. in the below example remove the row.

With my code it removes the correct row but I don't see the highlighting of this row before that.

**How do I tell it to wait x milliseconds before the next step and** (for other examples) **how do I set it to reverse back to the original color after that** (usually I would use `.css('background-color', '')` for that).

**My jQuery:**

```
if($(this).closest('table').find('tbody > tr').length > 1) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
    }, 1200);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: put remove() inside timeout and .css() outside

Comment: So you want the background to toggle from one color to another? Are you wanting this to continue the loop or just loop once?

Comment: @NewToJS: Just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   if($(this).closest('table').find('tbody > tr').length > 1) {

       // Change background
       $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');

       var that = this;

       // Wait 1.2 seconds, then remove the row
       setTimeout(function(){           
          $(that).closest('tr').remove();
       }, 1200);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - if the event would not be removing the tr would I need to set the background back manually then as well ?

Comment: Updated the example above to use a "selfie" for the scope of "this". Let me know if it doesn't work for you.